# How to test custom virtual audio device with shorter feedback loop?

Tags: macos, core-audio

I'm trying to create what's essentially a [Krisp](https://krisp.ai/) clone that creates a virtual audio device that will process my audio input using [RNNoise](https://github.com/xiph/rnnoise/). As a starting point, I'm using this example from the CoreAudio documentation: [Creating an Audio Server Driver Plug-in](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudio/creating_an_audio_server_driver_plug-in). The first milestone I'm trying to achieve is to simply create an "echo" virtual audio input device that will mirror the input of a real input device such as a microphone with no processing.

What I've found so far is that testing is very cumbersome - I have to install the built plugin to `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL` and then reboot my Mac. Is there a way to get a shorter feedback loop that does not involve rebooting?

Disclaimer: I have 0 experience with both macOS and audio programming. I also have almost no experience with C. If there's already an app that implements what I'm trying to achieve for free, I would be more than happy to use it instead of building my own.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo launchctl kickstart -k system/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod` does exactly what I want.